# reverse a list of Ordered pair in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of Ordered pair in python like `[(1,45),(21,28),(43,110),(4,81)]` and I want to reverse each items in list like `[(45,1),(28,21),(110,43),(81,4)]`.
what should I do?

Comment: Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 6):

Just use a list comprehension with tuple unpacking, it's as simple as:

```
ls = [(1,45),(21,28),(43,110),(4,81)]
new_ls = [(m, n) for n, m in ls]
print(new_ls)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [(45, 1), (28, 21), (110, 43), (81, 4)]
> ```

Comment: ok how can I compare two Ordered pair list?

Comment: @Niloofar You should probably make a new question for that :) P.S. feel free to [mark this as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/510616) if you feel like it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
list_ = [(1,45),(21,28),(43,110),(4,81)]
new_list = [item[::-1] for item in list_]
```

**Output** :

```
[(45, 1), (28, 21), (110, 43), (81, 4)]
```

Comment: It's very useful. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [(1,45),(21,28),(43,110),(4,81)]

sol = list(map(lambda x:x[::-1], l))
print(sol)
```

output

```
[(45, 1), (28, 21), (110, 43), (81, 4)]
```